# Play, route parsing and Hypermedia APIs

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

Let's say I have a file like this in my `routes` file:

```
 GET     /api/jobs/:hash                 controllers.Jobs.read(hash)
```

Now, I understand that if such a request is made, Play can route it to `controllers.Jobs.read` with the correct `hash` parameter inserted to trigger an `Action` and return a `Result`.  Furthermore, I understand that I can route `routes.Jobs.read.url(hash)` to generate the path giving me back the string `/api/jobs/${hash}` (which is great, I use it all the time).

But I've got a different use case (from those above) and I'm wondering if Play can help me with that as well.  What I want to do (and Play must be doing somewhere internally) is to take a given path, e.g. `/api/jobs/12345` and then pass it to a function which will simply return to me an `Option[String]` representing the hash parameter (assuming it is a valid route) but **not** invoke the action.

I would expect somewhere there is an auto-generated function like `routeparsers.Jobs.read(url: String): Option[String]` or, perhaps, more generally `routeparser.Jobs.read(url: String): Map[String,String]`.  I looked through some of the generated code, but I don't see any such utility functions (at least not ones I recognize).

Just to make things clear, the issue here is with hypermedia APIs where the users of the API will be passing me requests where the **body** (JSON in my case) refers to resources by their URLs.  I need to be able to translate those URLs into references to actual server side resources and to do that, I need to first confirm they are the correct format to refer to a resource of the expected type (i.e. they conform to the pattern) and then extract the critical parameters that I can then use to identify the server side resource.  So the key thing is that I'm not using these URLs to trigger an `Action`, I'm just using them to try and identify server side resources.  For obvious reasons, the URL patterns I'm interested in are going to be the ones associated with GET requests in my `routes` file.

I'm hoping that a) since this is very necessary functionality for hypermedia APIs and b)  Play has to do pretty much all of this anyway at some point during routing that there is a reasonably straightforward way to access this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be a little late, but I just stumbled about your question.

The closest thing to what you are searching is the router [API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.core.Router%24%24Routes) itself you can access it via `Application.router` (this is documented since 2.2, but it may also work in 2.1).

The `Router` object has a `handlerFor` method, which should be what you want (although in a slightly lowlevel way).